# Limpar campos de um formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Então moçada eu to com um problema aqui que é o seguinte:

Eu tenho 2 formulários. O formulario2 que fica dentro do formulario1. E eu queria um botao pra resetar apenas os campos do formulario 2. Só que o input type="reset" que eu coloco dentro do formulário 2, acaba limpando os 2 formulários.

Teria como eu fazer um botão apenas pra limpar os campos do formulário2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTML` explicitamente proíbe a inserção de `form` dentro de outro `form`.

[veja aqui](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element)

Nesta parte:

> Content model:
>   Flow content, but ***with no form element descendants***.

Nesta parte destacada do link, está dizendo quais tipos de categorias de conteúdo um `form` pode ter dentro dele. No caso pode ter elementos pertencente às categorias de conteúdo de fluxo, exceto outro elemento `form`. (A exceção se deve ao fato de que `form` é um elemento pertencente à categoria conteúdo de fluxo). Veja mais [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Categorias_de_conteudo).

Uma possível alternativa, seria isso:

```js
$('input.limpar').on('click', function() {

  
  $('div.campos').find('input').val('');

});
```

```css
input {

  display: block;
  
  margin-top: 5px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>

  <input type="text" value="campo 1" />
  <input type="text" value="campo 2" />
  <input type="text" value="campo 3" />
  
  <div class="campos">
    
  <input type="text" value="campo 4" />
  <input type="text" value="campo 5" />
  <input type="text" value="campo 6" />
    
  </div>
  
  <input class="limpar" type="button" value="limpar" />
  
</form>
```

Comment: Poxa, desde já obrigado pelo toque ai! Mas teria alguma outra forma?

Comment: @JaiderMasterInfo, você pode deixar um form só. Aí, você envolve os campos do formulário que você quer limpar em um div. Pra limpar, crie um botão que ao clicar procure todos os camos dessa nova div e retire os valores. Estou no trabalho agora, meio enrolado. Quando aliviar posso criar um exemplo aqui.

Comment: Beleza cara, se puder dar essa força ai, valeu mesmo!

Comment: @JaiderMasterInfo, editei minha resposta com um exemplo. Dá uma olhada e veja se consegue adaptar para as suas necessidades. Qq coisa, estamos aí!

Comment: Vey fino demais! Era bem isso mesmo! Valeu!!!!